# Run task sequence in parallel in Fake

Tags: f#, f#-fake

Would like to speed up builds using FAKE. Theoretically if I could run a build sequence in parallel (within a target) that should make it faster.

```
let buildProject outputDir buildTargets projectName = 
    let setParams p =
        { p with
            Verbosity = Some(Quiet)
            Targets = buildTargets
            Properties =
                [   "DevEnvDir", "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools"
                    "OutputPath", outputDir
                    "Optimize", "True"
                    "DebugSymbols", "True"
                    "Configuration", buildMode ]
            }
    build setParams projectName |> DoNothing

Target "BuildLibs" (fun _ -> 
    !! "**/*.csproj"
    -- "**/*.Tests.csproj"
    //A way to run in parallel??
    |> Seq.iter (buildProject buildOutDir ["ReBuild"])
)
```

Is there a way to run the sequence iteration in parallel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest option would be:

```
Target "BuildLibs" (fun _ -> 
    !! "**/*.csproj"
    -- "**/*.Tests.csproj"
    |> Seq.ToArray
    |> Array.Parallel.iter (buildProject buildOutDir ["ReBuild"])
)
```

Another alternative is "[F# Parallel Sequences](http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharp.Collections.ParallelSeq/)" component.

```
#r "./PATHTOLIB/lib/net40/FSharp.Collections.ParallelSeq.dll"
open FSharp.Collections.ParallelSeq

Target "BuildLibs" (fun _ -> 
    !! "**/*.csproj"
    -- "**/*.Tests.csproj"
    |> PSeq.iter (buildProject buildOutDir ["ReBuild"])
)
```